# Can't get the id name using onClick?

Tags: javascript, url, onclick, undefined

http://wthdesign.net/test/test.html

What I'm trying to do is append the id name into my url, but I'm getting "#undefined" instead?

The script I'm using:

```
function generateUrl()
{
    var currentId = $(this).attr('id');
    document.location.hash = currentId;
    console.log($(this));
}
```

inside the html:

```
<a id="abc" onClick="generateUrl()" >this is an anchor btn</a>
```

Comment: What do you get from the console log?

Comment: i got this:
[Window, jquery: "1.9.1", constructor: function, init: function, selector: "", size: function…]

Comment: You can change your link to `<a href="#abc">this is an anchor btn</a>` and will achieve the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you debug, you'll find that `this` in this context is the window object.  You can pass `this` into the function like so:

```
function generateUrl(el)
{
    var currentId = $(el).attr('id');
    document.location.hash = currentId;
}
```

```
<a id="abc" onClick="generateUrl(this)" >this is an anchor btn</a>
```

Alternatively, you can use jquery to replace your inline `onClick` like so:

```
$("#abc").click(function()
{
    var currentId = $(this).attr('id');
    document.location.hash = currentId;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<a id="abc" onClick="generateUrl(this)" >this is an anchor btn</a>


function generateUrl(elem)
{
    var currentId = elem.id;
    document.location.hash = currentId;

}
```

You pass the element to your function with "this"

Comment: You're mixing two different things here.  Either pass `this` or use `e.target`.

Comment: `e` is misleading however, because the variable name suggests that an event object will be passed.

Comment: @bozdoz, Yes, any names would have worked, even `sslkdjfsalkfj`, but I think you should put something that is more descriptive, like `linkElement` or `el` instead of using a variable name that represents an event object by convention! ;) Just an advice hehe!

Comment: Your request has been fulfilled. I adjusted the function argument to "elem"..  Cheers! :)

Answer (score 2):

That's because setting `onclick` HTML attribute is equivalent to set an anonymous function like this:

```
element.onclick = function(event) {
    generateUrl();
}
```

As you can see, in your call you lost both `event` object and `this` contextual object, that becomes the global ones (`window` for the browsers).

Then you have several approach. First, don't use the HTML attribute, but set the click by JS instead, that is a better practice – avoid spaghetti code, when it's possible.

You're using jQuery, therefore:

```
$(function() {
    $("#abc").click(generateUrl);
});
```

Plus, your function can be simplified:

```
function generateUrl() {
    window.location.hash = this.id;
}
```

So your HTML will be just:

```
<a id="abc">this is an anchor btn</a>
```

If, for any reason, you can't / don't want remove the `onclick` from the HTML, you have to modify it a bit:

```
<a id="abc" onClick="generateUrl.call(this)" >this is an anchor btn</a>
```

In that way you're calling the function passing the right contextual object. Just as future reference, you could also pass the `event` as first argument:

```
<a id="abc" onClick="generateUrl.call(this, event)" >this is an anchor btn</a>
```

P.S.
Notice that without an `href` attribute in your `a` tag, the browser won't threat that tag as a "link".

Comment: Thans for the detail explanation, your post do help explaining why using "this" wont work. Really appreciate that =)